# How do I test Observable.websocket by responding with message in RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I have some RXJS code that does something like the following....

```
this.webSocketSubject = Observable.webSocket(url);
...
get webSocketStream() {
    return this.webSocketSubject;
}


// Other Service
this.socketService.webSocketStream.filter(message => {
        return message.method === "logout";
}).subscribe( this.onLogout );
```

Then in my test I try something like this...

```
socketService.sendMessage = jasmine.createSpy("Send Message Spy").and.callFake(function() {
                socketService.webSocketStream.next(
                    {
                        method: "logout",
                        status: "OK"
                    }
                )
});
// Just to confirm but doesn't get called
socketService.webSocketStream.subscribe(message => console.log("Ok it actually got called"))
```

But the subscribe code never gets called. I looked for other examples of test WS in RxJS but all I see is [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/observables/dom/webSocket-spec.ts) and I can't get something similar working locally.

How do I test Observable.websocket in RxJS?

Answer (score 0):

I had to resort to this but I don't like it.

`constructor(private socket: Subject<any> = undefined ) {
        if(!socket){
            this.webSocketSubject = Observable.webSocket(url);
        }
        else{
            this.webSocketSubject = socket;
        }
};`